# Is this layout possible using html? if yes then how to write C2 and C3?

Tags: html, html-table, division

How is this Web page layout structure / table is possible to code in HTML?

[image]

Comment: Brain sir how can i view image on below post using edit option functionality.

Comment: I feel like this post is just an easy way for us to do your task for you. Of course, it is possible but you'll nee to post some code before we can assist you, do you have anything so far?

Comment: This question is much too broad to be answerable as is.  There are several different ways to do this, including flexbox or CSS grid; which will be best for you depends on your HTML structure, how much the content within each block might vary, how you need the layout to respond to different screen sizes, and quite a few other factors.

Comment: The layout is possible, you just need to design the page with CSS and HTML. Your question is very broad which is discouraged on StackOverFlow. I think you should spend some time to explore HTML and CSS with more simplified HTML pages. After learning HTML and CSS a little more you should be more prepared to design your HTML structure and add CSS to accomplish your goal with your own strength.

Answer (score -2):

This is possible, it is a little bit complex in the terms of how you would need to do it.

Basically, start from left to right and use  tags for each:

```
<div id="student"></div> 
<div id="C2"></div>
<div id="top_right">

<div id="Home"></div>
<div id="Admin"></div>
<div id="Contact"></div>
<div id="quick"></div>

</div>
```

So, im just doing the first part. For the top layer you would want to use

```
float: left;   //on each <div> in the css
```

and then when it came to the "quick" div you would want to

```
clear: both;
float: left; //in the css as well
```

This is a really quick example, obviously you would need to have the correct width and height for each but if you use float and clear correctly you can achieve this layout

Comment: Floats get messy very easily and quickly. Would be much cleaner to get most of the layout by changing the CSS `display` property and using pure HTML structure.

Comment: I honestly disagree I've never had a problem with Floats, but i do understand that for some people new to HTML it can be difficult

Comment: A significant problem with floats is in their indirect effect on the layout of siblings and on the containing element -- they can work fine when tested in isolation but then cause overlapping or zero-height collapse if the content in various nearby nodes changes, necessitating clearfix hacks etc.  Float is really best reserved for elements which actually need to be floated inside a longer text; routinely misusing it for all horizontal layout is analogous to using tables for layout: sure, it can be done, but there are much better techniques.  (`display: inline-block`, in this case.)

Comment: i do agree with you on the inline-block